# Partial differential equation with partial derivative at fixed values of other parameters

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristic-functions

Let us consider the following family of partial differential equations
$$
\frac{\partial G(x,y,t)}{\partial t} = a(x) \frac{\partial G(x,y,t)}{\partial x} + b(y) \frac{\partial G(x,y,t)}{\partial y} + c(x,y) \frac{\partial G(x,0,t)}{\partial x}
$$
If there was not the last term, this equation could be solved with the method of the characteristics. How can one deal with terms of the type $\frac{\partial G(x,0,t)}{\partial x}$?

For the specific problem I am studying, I am interested in the case
$$
a(x) = b(x) = (1-x)( 1- \alpha x)
$$
and
$$
c(x,y) = \beta x(y-1)
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are parameters, and
 boundary condition
$$
G(x,y,0) = x
$$